# Using P/Invokes in Mono through Wine

Tags: .net, mono, pinvoke, wine

Is it possible to use native Win API functions in Mono through Wine? Are there some additional libraries for interactions between Mono and Wine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will only work if you install and use the Windows version of Mono *inside* the Wine environment. No additional libraries should be needed. However, P/Invoke that affects the Windows Forms GUI likely won't work, because Mono's Windows Forms doesn't actually wrap native controls, but instead is implemented using fully managed code.

There's probably a better way to do what you want, if you could be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Just some helpful tidbits I've found so far:

Looks like Mono [does support P/Invoke](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) (half way down you'll see a section on Marshalling).

So, I think it could potentially work, if Wine correctly supports the Win API call you're trying to make.  You'll never really be able to call the *native* Win API function, but if there's a Wine interpretation, theoretically it should work.  Just make sure to run your Mono project inside of Wine.

Any reason you're not virtualizing and running Mono on Windows itself?

Comment: I know that mono supports native P/Invoke. But I want to use some console winapi calls in Linux environment.

Comment: I think it should just be a matter of looking up your calls and seeing if there's a Wine implementation yet.  Do you have a list of specific calls by any chance?